# Edit Metadata of PDF File with C/C++?

Tags: c++, pdf, metadata

Could anyone please provide me a sample C/C++ code to read and edit PDF Metadata?

If it is XMP, what else to do?

Answer (score 1):

If it's XMP, I think there's an SDK available from Adobe. But beware, PDF metadata has a long history and isn't only stored in XMP.

You might best be off using a library that allows PDF manipulation. There are several commercial ones available. I have no idea whether there's something usable available for free.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hfiguiere/exempi -- C-library to read and write XMP.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried [XMPToolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp/) yet, give it a shot and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The XMP SDK from adobe does not read/write metadata of PDF files. PDF reading/writing is a complicated task. Your best bet is to use a third party PDF library, or commands like [pdfleo](http://rockpdf.com).